# 9 Amps on Ethernet?

Tags: power, pcb, current

I already did my search but I found nothing to confirm it. 
I have a PCB and I want to connect a jumper that can carry up to 9 Amps. I tried a zero ohm resistance but it melted so I want to use an Ethernet cable as a jumper.

**The main question is what is my limit the current or the power dissipated?**

On wiki it says max current is 0.5 but on power calculation power will be less that 0.5 watt. 
Cat5 has 10 ohms / 100 meter

$$ P = 9 \times 9 \times \dfrac{10}{100 \times 100} \times 3 \; cm $$

Comment: google ampacity calculator or similar

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you.

Comment: How long is this proposed jumper wire?

Comment: @JImDearden 3 cm

Comment: What I don't understand about your question is why you specifically mention ethernet (designed for data transmission) - This question has nothing to do with data transmission. Surely all you need is an ordinary piece of insulated wire capable of carrying 10+ amps - at 3cm length you could even use a piece of 15A fuse wire.

Comment: I have the pcb already made and I can use the Ethernet wire for it is one wire and fits with the size of the holes.

Comment: Are you referring to the entire 4-twisted-pair cat-5/6/x Ethernet cable, or just to a single wire which you have stripped out of an Ethernet cable?

Comment: @brhans Single wire.

Answer (score 1):

10 Amps over an ethernet cable? Uh..no, definitely not.
Conductors aren't thick enough.

The ability of a wire (cable) to carry current is dependent on the cross sectional area of the wire. The wire heats up, the more current it carries (basic electrical theory), the power lost (and hence increase in wire's temperature) is related to the square of the current and also to the resistance of the cable.

As you make the wire thicker the cross sectional area increases and the resistance decreases, which means the power lost and temperature rise is lower.

So in theory, a wire can carry any amount of current, it's just a case of how hot you are willing to allow it to get, and what what voltage drop you can tolerate across it. You might have 12 Volts at one end, but you'll have less at the other end, caused by the resistance.

In practise, a wire can't carry any amount of current because the more you push down it, the hotter it gets until either the insulation or wire (copper or whatever metal its made from) melts and breaks.

I find the following website useful, it allows you to experiment with different amounts of loss you can tolerate.  This will calculate what kind of thickness cable you need (reported as the cross sectional area of the wire, expressed in mm2 (square milimetres). The AWG gauge is also given.

http://www.solar-wind.co.uk/cable-sizing-DC-cables.html

Comment: But with 3 cm wire the resistance is so low as in 0.003 ohm so the power is low. So it won't heat too much. Is there a problem with high current if the power lost as heat is far lower than the limit ?

Comment: The effects to worry about are:heating of the wire, the strength of the magnetic field produced by the wire(which generally isn't a problem).The greater the current, the greater it will heat up, and the greater the magnetic field produced from it.If neither of these are a problem then you can use the wire, even if it is thin.Be aware that changing magnetic fields induce voltages & currents in other components and wires nearby.So 10Amp,if that current varies then the magnetic field produced from the wire will vary and could induce a voltage in nearby electronics.  Might not be an issue for you.

Comment: @Abkarino, if the wire is shorter, it will dissipate less power. But it will also have less mass to heat up, so it will still (roughly) fail at the same temperature. There is some benefit to using a shorter wire if the two ends are connected to heat sinks, but working out how much you could up-rate a short wire probably requires an FEM simulation. It's easier to just use the standard ampacity tables, and accept the improved reliability as a side-benefit.

Comment: @ThePhoton Make it as an answer so I could choose it.
You wrote what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ethernet cable you pulled your single wire from to (hopefully) see what gauge (thickness) it is. It 'should' be printed on the cable at regular intervals.

The one I have on my desk reads "24AWG", so its a 24 on the American Wire Gauge table.

Then go to a cable 'ampacity' table or calculator (http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm is one, but there are loads of options) and see what the safe current limit is for your cable.

Of course the numbers listed in these sort of tables are usually a bit on the conservative side and may or may not take into account whether or not you've got a bunch of wires bundled together (affects heat dissipation).

You could also look up the fusing current of your gauge of wire (the point at which the metal conductor will melt) and make very sure you stay far, far, far away from that value ...

Comment: From that table, for 24 AWG, would the current rating be 3.5A (chassis wiring), or .58A (power transmission) - I am leaning towards the former due to the short distance the OP needs, but I am not sure